# Retrieve data from MS Access Database and display in JTable

Tags: java, ms-access, jtable

I am trying to get data from a database and display them into a JTable in Java.
Now I have a working code which does retrieve the data and displays it in the table but somehow it does not display the first column. Anybody an idea?
Here my code:

```
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

        while (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }

        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row[i-1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
```

**UPDATE**

Ok I tried using Vector and it happens the same thing. My database has the following columns: ID, Subject, AS1, AS2
Now I do get the data displayed in the JTable, but the order of my row data always starts with the Subject column first, then AS1, then AS2 and last ID.
Why is this happening?

Comment: If the query you are executing is `SELECT * FROM ...` then try using `SELECT ID, Subject, AS1, AS2 FROM ...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around it by creating another Object[] and assigning the last object from the first array to the first of array two.

```
while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row[i-1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }

                Object sub = row[0];
                Object ses = row[1];
                Object as1 = row[2];
                Object as2 = row[3];
                Object as3 = row[4];
                Object fe = row[5];
                Object id = row[6];                   

                Object[] row2 = new Object[columns];
                row2[0] = id;
                row2[1] = sub;
                row2[2] = ses;
                row2[3] = as1;
                row2[4] = as2;
                row2[5] = as3; 
                row2[6] = fe;

            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row2);
        }
```

Not beautiful but it gets the job done.